# What datatype does Google Datastore use for legacy mode auto generated ids?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I have a client application that uses integers to store Datastore ids. This was working fine as the Datastore ids used to be sequencially generated but now needs to be  changed to auto generated to scale. The two options for autogenerating are default and legacy. The default option uses long datatype and hence will break the client. The legacy says it generates small integers but is there a guarantee that it won't cross to the long datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Datastore keys uses ids (long ints, 64-bit) or names (string). The auto-incrementing legacy id allocation starts off with small numbers, but given enough entities it will eventually exceed what can be stored in just a 32-bit int.